# hadoop - Map reduce on multiple cluster

Tags: java, python, hadoop, mapreduce

I have configured Hadoop cluster . And im having two machines **MA** and **MB**
When i run the mapreduce program using the following code

```
 hadoop  jar /HDP/hadoop-1.2.0.1.3.0.0-0380/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-1.2.0.1.3.0.0-0380.jar  -mapper "python C:\Python33\mapper.py"  -reducer "python C:\Python33\redu.py"  -input "/user/XXXX/input/input.txt"  -output "/user/XXXX/output/out20131112_09"
```

**where : mapper - C:\Python33\mapper.py and reducer C:\Python33\redu.py is in  MB's local disk**

**UPDATE**
[image]

Finally i have tracked down the error .

MA- error log

```
stderr logs
python: can't open file 'C:\Python33\mapper.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 2
```

**mapper - C:\Python33\mapper.py and reducer C:\Python33\redu.py is in  MA's local disk** and it is not in **MB**

Now , Do i need to copy my m/r program to **MA** or how shall i resolve this

**Mapper**

```
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
   line = line.strip()
   keys = line.split()
   for key in keys:
       value = 1
       print( '%s \t %d' % (key, value))
```

Comment: please refer to http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HowManyMapsAndReduces

Comment: @alko from the above picture you can find that the input is spitted into multiple blocks in DEV144 machine .. Am i right?

Comment: from your log it seems that on dev140 one map task was successfully run, and one failed 4 times in a row. that contradicts with your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the map input file is smaller than `dfs.block.size` then you will end with only one task per job running. For small inputs you can force Hadoop to run multiple tasks with   `mapred.max.split.size` value in bytes being smaller than `dfs.block.size`.

Comment: my input.txt in of 145 MB . How to check those properties you have mentioned . Kindly help me im newbie to hadoop family

Comment: you can access the JobTracker information at DEV144:50030. There you will see all the registered map/reduce nodes. Check that max tasks(map/reduce) per each client are greater than 0. When the job is running go in the Jobtracker and then select the running task you will be able to see all the properties from the job configuration file and compare the values.

Comment: It seems that both nodes had some completed tasks, so it is safe to assume that the tasks are being scheduled on both machines. Check your logs on DEV140 to track down the source of the errors.

Comment: It looks like your mapper is failing to find a file. Make sure that you make distinction between HDFS files and disk files. Can you post the code from your mapper.

Comment: I have added the mapper program

Comment: im able to run MapReduce on both machine if both DEV114 and DEV140 has the mapper.py and redu.py in their local drive . And my doubt is do i need to copy my maper and reducer program to all the machines

Comment: You are right, try to have the same environment/files (mapper and reducer) on both machines.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41096/discussion-between-backtrack-and-ion-cojocaru)

Comment: Kindly have a look on this http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.1.2/streaming.html                          he executables do not need to pre-exist on the machines in the cluster; however, if they don't, you will need to use "-file" option to tell the framework to pack your executable files as a part of job submission. For example:

$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop  jar $HADOOP_HOME/hadoop-streaming.jar \
    -input myInputDirs \
    -output myOutputDir \
    -mapper myPythonScript.py \
    -reducer /bin/wc \
    -file myPythonScript.py